# How to do this rewrite rule for apache htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to make rewrite that would take get.domain.com to domain.com/get.php alongside all GET parameters.

Example: get.domain.com?v=64 would change to domain.com/get.php?v=64

Also, if possible, I would like the request URL on the webpage not to change, and remain as get.domain.com?v=64 to the user.

My current attempt:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?get\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/get.php [NE,R=301,L]
```

It does translate get.domain.com to domain.com/get.php but paramters are not transferred and the URL is changing.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Are `get.domain.com` and `domain.com` pointing to same directory?

Comment: They are. Both are pointing to the same IP

Comment: And for that, typing get.domain.com is loading the domain.com page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(get)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %1.php [L]
```

Comment: I see. But would that transfer the GET parameters too?

Comment: It is not working. get.domain.com redirects properly but get.domain.com?v=64 does not redirect to domain.com/get.php?v=64

Comment: Also, when visiting get.domain.com it redirects but the request URL is changing I want it to remain get.domain.com

Comment: I just tested again in Chrome developer tools. URL did not change but get.domain.com redirected to domain.com and not domain.com/get.php

Comment: My htaccess contains the rule you specied only. It conaints a RewriteEngine On too. Could there me something else afftecting this? Again, it is redirecting to domain.com instead of domain.com/get.php